# Django models and relationships . error

Tags: django, django-models

Hi guys I have I guess a simple proving that I am missing something using models and relationships
I have two models models one is a Team, that can have multiple user, and a user can be part of multiple teams
and a project which get a name and is tied to on Team

```
class Team(models.Model):
    member1 = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank= False)
    member2 = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank= False)
    member3 = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank= True)
    member4 = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank= True)
    member5 = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank= True)
    member6 = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank= True)


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

When I try to migrate a get a big error

```
website.Team.member1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Team.member1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Team.m
ember2'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Team.member1' or 'Team.member2'.
website.Team.member1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Team.member1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Team.m
ember3'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Team.member1' or 'Team.member3'.
website.Team.member1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Team.member1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Team.m
ember4'.
```

I know that I am missing something, could you help me to figure it out ? 
Thx

Comment: Please, don't add all the possible keyword to your question.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: Note that the solution is already provided by the message.

Comment: Yes I just do not know what it means .. ;(